# ReactiveUI - WhenActivated and Output Properties

Tags: c#, xamarin, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm using [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/) and I'm trying to change all my ViewModels' rules with [WhenActivated](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/) but I'm unable understand how to have it working well in conjunction with output properties.

The pattern is something like

```
this.WhenActivated(
registerDisposable =>
{
    registerDisposable(this.Bind(…));
    registerDisposable(this.WhenAny(…));
    registerDisposable(this.WhenAnyValue(…));
});
```

and the output properties looks like

```
protected readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<object> _Obj;
public object Obj => _Obj.Value
_Obj = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Something).ToProperty(this, x => x.Obj, out _Obj);
```

So the only way I see to unite these is:

```
class MyClass {

protected readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<object> _Obj;
public object Obj => _Obj.Value

public MyClass()
{
    _Obj = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Something).ToProperty(this, x => x.Obj, out _Obj);

    this.WhenActivated( registerDisposable =>
    {
        registerDisposable(_Obj);
    });
}
```

}

Will this work as expected or there is another better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, _Obj doesn't need to be disposed of because *Something* has the same scope as _Obj (they're both contained within MyClass). However, if you were to base _Obj off of an observable contained in a service - which commonly has a longer lifetime than a view model - then you'd need to dispose of it.

```
// _Obj should be disposed of, in this case.
_Obj = someService
    .SomePipeline
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Obj)
```

Side note: you don't need to use the out parameter if you're assigning to a value. The following is equivalent to the above:

```
someService
    .SomePipeline
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Obj, out _Obj)
```

So in the case of someService, you *could* put _Obj inside WhenActivated but it

> creates sticky race conditions whereby the OAPH may be null when it's
>   corresponding property (Obj) is accessed too early.

This info, as well as the quote above, is taken straight from Kent Boogaart's book, ["You, I, and ReactiveUI."](https://reactiveui.net/blog/2018/04/you-i-and-reactiveui)

He was kind enough to provide a solution for the above scenario that turns activation into a pipeline. You can use [these extensions](https://github.com/kentcb/YouIandReactiveUI/blob/76170605f378cbe3c3e09403bf8211b249b2ed1c/ViewModels/Samples/Chapter%2018/Sample%2006/GetIsActivatedExtensions.cs) (the first for view models and the second for views) like this:

```
_Obj = this
    .GetIsActivated()
    .Select(isActivated => isActivated ? someService.SomePipeline : Observable.Return(null))
    .Switch()
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Obj);
```